# An identity involving alternative sum of triple product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, alternating-expression

I can not motivative the problem to be honest, but the following identity has shown up in my research. I have verified the identity for large enough values of $k$ using sagemath. Now, I want to prove it:
$$\binom{2k}{k}\left[\sum_{r=0}^k\ (-1)^r\binom{k}{r}\binom{3k-r}{k-r}\binom{3k-r}{k}\right]=(-1)^k\left[\sum_{r=0}^{2k} (-1)^r\binom{2k}{r}^4\right].$$

At first I tried to evaluate the right hand side but couldn't. I could see that there is a similar identity (Dixon's identity when the exponent is $3$). I am clueless what to do with the left hand side! After everything gone, once I tried to prove the identity by mathematical induction on $k$ but as expected, it turned out to be a horrible task.

Any suggestion or comments will be highly appreciable.

**Notations:** $\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient i.e. the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^n.$

**Edited:** The last binomial factor should be $\binom{3k-r}{k}$ instead of $\binom{2k-r}{k}.$

Comment: The sequence is also known as [de Bruijn's S(4,n)](https://oeis.org/A050983).

Comment: Thanks. Yes. The right hand side. That we know. But wondering how to show that this is equal to the left hand side. I have even checked with the de Brujin's original paper, there asymptotic behaviors of this sequence has been studied. I was wondering if there is any recurrence relation which this sequence satisfies!

Comment: I wonder if [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm) can tackle this...

Comment: A useless fact: RHS is expressible as
$$
(-1)^k [x^{2k} y^{2k} z^{2k} s^{2k}]\frac{1}{1+sy+ xz+ sxy + sxz + syz + xyz+2sxyz}
$$

Comment: Wait, are you sure your expression is correct? When I put $k=2$, I get $366$ in LHS, and $786$ in RHS.

Comment: I guess LHS should actually have $\binom{3k-r}{k}$, not $\binom{2k-r}{k}$.

Comment: So, with this change, LHS is also expressible as
$$
[x^{2k} y^k z^k](1+z)^{2k} (1+x)^{2k} (1+y)^{2k} (xy+x+y)^k
$$
But it doesn't look like a good expression, especially given that $xy+x+y$ is non-linear and prevents us from using MacMahon's theorem.

Comment: @OleksandrKulkov Oops, thanks for pointing that out. Edited. It should be $\binom{3k-r}{k}$ instead of $\binom{2k-r}{k}.$

Comment: There is one interpretation for the RHS. The right hand side is the constant term of the rational function $$(i+ixyz)^{2k}(1-x^{-1}yz)^{2k}(1+y^{-2})^{2k}(1+z^{-2})^{2k},$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}.$ This expression doesn't look good either.